# Bing Maps API for WPF Culture change

Tags: c#, wpf, localization, cultureinfo, bing-maps

When I try to set the culture of the map like this:

```
<WPF:Map Culture="pt-BR" />
```

All the labels remains in english and don't change the culture.

My Windows language is english, but I want to force pt-BR in the map.

I alread changed my application culture my setting the main Thread culture, UICulture and putting pt-BR in the csproject file, but the map remains in english.

I really need to change this because in english the name of São Paulo city is "Sao Paolo".

Answer (score 0):

The WPF control was released at a time when Bing Maps only supported a small number of cultures. Doing some testing it appears that only the following cultures are supported by this map control:

- fr-FR
- fr-CA
- nl-BE
- en-US
- de-DE
- it-IT
- ja-JP
- es-ES
- es-MX
- es-US

I'll pass this information on to our documentation team so that it's easier to figure this out in the future. I'll also add a feature request for additional language support in future versions of the WPF control.